# See apple-app-site-association file in .well-known directory despite RewriteCond

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apple-app-site-associate

In my sites hosted on Dreamhost, the `.well-known` directory contains an *acme-challenge* folder along with an `.htaccess` like this:

```
# Permit access to the challenge files but nothing else
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[.]well-known/acme-challenge/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Therefore when I put my *apple-app-site-association* file into `.well-known`, it isn't seen. How would I modify the `.htaccess` to permit this? Would I just stick in another line such as

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /.well-known/apple-app-site-association
```

?? I don't want to break anything and I know virtually nothing of the syntax in these files, so I'm being rather hesitant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your first rule like this with an `OR` condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[\w-]+/?$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\.well-known/apple-app-site-association/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Or it can be combined in a single condition also:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\.well-known/(?:acme-challenge/[\w-]+|apple-app-site-association)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try immediately. (I'm sure that answer is obvious to you but it would never have occurred to me in a million years.)

Comment: (It occurs to me that I should explain, in case anyone comes along and sees this, what "working" means. (1) `https://` links into my web site still work. So we are still seeing the certificates, which is what the `acme-challenge` stuff was all about. (2) I was able to configure a test iOS app and the `apple-app-site-association` file, living in the `.well-known` directory, such that an `https://` link of a certain form is routed to my app — in other words, universal links are working.)